# How can I convert several jpgs into single multi-page pdf file?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, png, jpeg

I have several `.jpg` files, named sequentially from `a.jpg` to `j.jpg`. I tried simply concatenating them into single `pdf` file:

```
convert *.jpg output.pdf
```

but then I saw that two of the images were a little higher than the others:

```
$ echo *.jpg | xargs -n1 identify
a.jpg JPEG 400x567 400x567+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 15.8KB 0.000u 0:00.000
b.jpg JPEG 400x567 400x567+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 18.7KB 0.000u 0:00.000
c.jpg JPEG 400x567 400x567+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 33.5KB 0.000u 0:00.000
d.jpg JPEG 400x567 400x567+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 24.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
e.jpg JPEG 400x751 400x751+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 39.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
f.jpg JPEG 400x567 400x567+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 31.6KB 0.000u 0:00.000
g.jpg JPEG 400x567 400x567+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 37.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000
h.jpg JPEG 400x567 400x567+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 32KB 0.000u 0:00.000
i.jpg JPEG 400x720 400x720+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 27.6KB 0.000u 0:00.000
j.jpg JPEG 400x567 400x567+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 5.65KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

As you see, `e.jpg` and `i.jpg` have a bigger height. I batch converted all the files to the same size:

```
for x in {a..j}; do convert $x.jpg -gravity center -background white -extent 400x751 $x.png; done;
```

Now all the resulting `.png` files have the same size:

```
$ echo *.png | xargs -n1 identify
a.png PNG 400x751 400x751+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 62.3KB 0.000u 0:00.000
b.png PNG 400x751 400x751+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 74.9KB 0.000u 0:00.000
c.png PNG 400x751 400x751+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 148KB 0.000u 0:00.000
d.png PNG 400x751 400x751+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 85.5KB 0.000u 0:00.000
e.png PNG 400x751 400x751+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 175KB 0.000u 0:00.000
f.png PNG 400x751 400x751+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 124KB 0.000u 0:00.000
g.png PNG 400x751 400x751+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 162KB 0.000u 0:00.000
h.png PNG 400x751 400x751+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 118KB 0.000u 0:00.000
i.png PNG 400x751 400x751+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 113KB 0.000u 0:00.000
j.png PNG 400x751 400x751+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 15.7KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

But, batching them into the `pdf` file (`convert *.png output.pdf`) still results in those two pages being much bigger than others. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Seems I found the solution - I needed to specify `-density` option, when assembling pdf:

```
convert *.png -density 600 output.pdf
```

But still, I don't understand why it didn't work in the original attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the `img2pdf` Python CLI program for lossless conversion:

https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf

Example usage:

```
img2pdf img1.png img2.jpg -o out.pdf
```

Answer (score -3):

Simple add all your images in a doc file page by page and save the doc as pdf. If you are using Windows you can use Microsoft Word and if you are using Linux you can use Open Office.

Comment: No, that's not nice. This is just an example - if I will have hundreds of such images, it would take extremely high amount of time to do all this by hand. I need an automatic way.